# Why won't TwinCat 3 Analytics Data Logger connect to my MQTT server?

Tags: mqtt, plc, twincat

I am trying to use TwinCat 3 with TcAnalytics to create a Data Logger which logs values to MQTT. I have created this Data Logger, and set the settings to 127.0.0.1 and also created the same connection in my Target Browser under TcAnalytics.

The problem is that the PlcStream1 created for the Data Logger is showing 'Disconnected' in the Online tab at the same time as the Target Browser connection shows everything is fine and connected properly.

[image: screen shot]

I have seen a video of someone setting this up and the data stream from the Data Logger appears nested under the connection in the Target Browser once it's setup. For me this does not show up either.

I have tested my local MQTT server with a third party tool that can publish and subscribe to it just fine.

Why won't the Data Logger connect to MQTT and publish data to it?

My setting in the Data Logger 1 Parameter (Init) tab look accurate to me. They are shown below.

[image: settings]

Does anyone know how to get TcAnalytics to log data to MQTT? It seems like a really straight forward setup but it's just not connecting.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear here, is the MQTT broker running on exactly the same machine as where you are entering `127.0.0.1`? Or is that value being passed to a PLC as a remote address to connect to?

Comment: I have a this all running on a local machine. I'm connected via ethernet to a PLC which I hope to push it it. But running twin cat on the local machine, I'm still not able to get it running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that my MQTT server was not serving on all interfaces. Contrary to some data I found, Mosquitto doesn't serve to all interfaces by default. I needed to add this to my mosquitto.conf file.

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```